# Make Flathub update when I run apt update

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center, update-manager, flatpak

Ubuntu 18.04

I have Flathub added as a repo to update flatpaks that are installed. But I like to update my system with

```
 sudo apt update 

 sudo apt upgrade
```

Currently, I have to open the ubuntu software center and click update all to apply updates to the flatpaks that are appearing in the software center (added that feature per instructions on Flathub website.

**How can I make apt update apt upgrade, also update my flatpaks?**

Comment: `apt` is a front-end that works with deb packages; it knows nothing about snaps, flatpacks, appimages...  Canonical/Ubuntu have it add/upgrade snaps using deb/apt tools by having wrappers in deb format that cause the snap actions to occur; so this is one *messy* solution; the other is for you to have your own `apt` appear in the your $PATH ahead of the real `apt` that runs the real `apt` plus upgrades your own packages. Neither of these are ideal; as you want `apt` to do something it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: Well is there a tool to upgrade Deb packages AND flatpaks?